# Set counting problem with a cap on the intersection between the set and a fixed partition

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, enumerative-combinatorics

Fix sets $T_1,\ldots T_m$ as a $k$-partition of $[m\cdot k]=\{1,2,\ldots,m\cdot k\}$, so that $|T_i|=k$ and $|T_i\cap T_\ell|=0$.

1) For any $j\le k$, how many sets $C\subset [m\cdot k]$ are there such that $|C|=k$ and $\max_{i}|T_i\cap C| = j$?  Call this number $n(m,k,j)$ and call $N(m,k,j)$ the cumulative version where $\max_{i}|T_i\cap C| \le j$.

2) More generally, how many sets of the form $\{C_1,\ldots,C_m\}$ are there such that $C_1,\ldots,C_m$ is a $k$-partition of $[k\cdot m]$ where $\max_{i,\ell} |T_i\cap C_\ell| = j$?

Are asymptotic answers known/obvious for either of these two questions?

Note for the first question, an exact but clunky formula is given by the recursion:
$$N(m,k,j) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & j < k/m \\ 
\binom{m}{k}k^k & j=1\text{ and }m\ge k\\
\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{j}\right\rfloor} \binom{m}{i} \binom{k}{j}^i N(m-i,k-ji,j-1) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ 
(Choose the $T_i$'s that get exactly $j$ elements of $C$, then the locations of the $j$ elements in each of the chosen $T_i$'s, then choose the rest.)

In addition, the probability that a (uniformly) random set will have intersection more than the mean $k/m$ can be lower-bounded by choosing each element of $C$ independently, then using Chernoff and union bounds: $P[\max_i(T_i\cap C)-k/m > t] \le k e^{-2t^2/k}$.  Then $$N(m,k,j) \ge N(m,k,k)(1-k e^{-2(j-\frac{k}{m})^2/k}).$$  A similar result can be shown for the second problem as well.  Is this bound asymptotically tight?

Comment: For the asymptotics that interest you, which parameters remain fixed and which go to infinity?

Comment: Just saw this comment.  I'm interested in the case when, for $n=mk$, $n$ goes to infinity, $k$ is a function of $n$, say $log(n)$, $m=n/k$, and $j$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

$N(m,k,j)$ equals the coefficient of $x^k$ in
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^j \binom{k}{i} x^i\right)^m.$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MarcoGolla: This is neither critique, nor request for clarification. While it's not a complete answer either,  it provides an insight into one of the quantities defined by the author. Comments do not format complex formulae nicely.